# React http with internal json file Request and advantage of axios over fetch method

Tags: json, reactjs, http

Recently I started learning reactjs and I want to call a JSON file from my directory structure to use data from the JSON file and also I have some confusion between Axios and fetch methods please help me to understand with a brief idea that what should I use and what are the good practice while using any of the methods.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this are the most common doubts for all the developers who started learning react now a days even I have faced same thing while I was learning so let me help you with my knowledge which I gain over period of time,

i). HTTP call on internal JSON.

So, for reactJS you want to use static JSON for that we need to understand about the react directory structure

[React directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmUH5.png)

so as you can see this structure you can see those folders where src is your main project folder and public is your assets kind of folder you need to put your JSON file into public folder so the once you run your react project you can easily get your file from public folder as we know every time we run npm start command the npm create a optimized bundle of the src folder so if you put your JSON file into that directory you will never get that.

ii). use of Axios and fetch.

this is a very debatable topic and the views will change developer by developer so let me put my views here,

Axios: this is a third party module that you can after installing that dependency the most this module provide you a layout as we use to like an ajax call you will response format in ajax manner.

Fetch: this is native JavaScript method for that you don't need any third party dependency and the response you will get slightly in different then we use to.

if you need any further details you can simply browse this topics there is many more blogs available from you can get better idea.